How to generate a hierarchical colourmap in matplotlib?
I have a hierarchical dataset that I wish to visualise in this manner. I've been able to construct a heatmap for it.

I want to generate a colormap in matplotlib such that Level 1 get categorical colours while Level 2 get different shades of the Level 1 colour. I was able to get Level 1 colours from a "tab20" palette but I can't figure out how to generate shades of the base Level 1 colour.
EDIT: Just to be clear, this needs to be a generic script. So I can't hard code the colormap.
MWE
At the moment this just creates a colormap based on the level 1 values. I am not sure how to generate the shades for the level 2 colours:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

df = pd.DataFrame({"Level 2": [4, 5, 6, 6, 7], "Level 1": [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]}).T

colours = mpl.colormaps["tab20"].resampled(len(df.loc["Level 1"].unique())).colors

colour_dict = {
    item: colour for item, colour in zip(df.loc["Level 1"].unique(), colours)
}

sns.heatmap(
    df,
    cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap([colour_dict[item] for item in colour_dict.keys()]),
)
colours

In this example, 4 and 5 should be shades of the colour for 0 and 6 and 7 should be shades of the colour for 1.
Edit 2
Applying @mozway's answer below, this is the heatmap I see:

This is with 423 values in level 2 and n=500.

Please provide a [mre] of what you currently have

@mozway ok added an MWE.

How many "level 1" can you have? Also should the color have the same "scale" (0->1 ; 0->100)?

@mozway There is no limit. The data is read from a CSV file. But as a heuristic I have gone with 20 (as signified by "tab20"). The scale of the values is irrelevant. My data is actually categorical. I just convert it to integer values for plotting.

What about combining several gradients to form a multi-colored cmap, then rescaling your data?
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

df = pd.DataFrame({"Level 2": [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5],
                   "Level 1": [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]}).T

n = 5 # max value per level
level1 = pd.factorize(df.loc['Level 1'])[0]*n
n_levels = df.loc['Level 1'].nunique()

cmap = mpl.colormaps['tab10']

i = np.linspace(0, 1, num=n_levels+1)
colors = list(zip(np.sort(np.r_[i, i[1:-1]-0.001]),
                  [x for c in cmap.colors[:n_levels+1]
                   for x in (c, 'w')]))

multi_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('hierachical', colors)

tmp = pd.DataFrame({'Level 2': level1+df.loc['Level 2'],
                    'Level 1': level1
                    }).T

sns.heatmap(tmp, cmap=multi_cmap, vmin=0, vmax=n*n_levels,
            square=True, cbar_kws={'orientation': 'horizontal'})

Output:

If you want to annotate with the real values:
sns.heatmap(tmp, annot=df, cmap=multi_cmap, vmin=0, vmax=n*n_levels,
            square=True, cbar_kws={'orientation': 'horizontal'})

Output:

further customization
If you want to reverse the order of the gradients:
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

df = pd.DataFrame({"Level 2": [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5],
                   "Level 1": [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]}).T

n = 5 # max value per level
level1 = pd.factorize(df.loc['Level 1'])[0]*n
n_levels = df.loc['Level 1'].nunique()

cmap = mpl.colormaps['tab10']

i = np.linspace(0, 1, num=n_levels+1)
colors = list(zip(np.sort(np.r_[i, i[1:-1]-0.001]),
                  [x for c in cmap.colors[:n_levels+1]
                   for x in ('w', c)]))

multi_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('hierachical', colors)

tmp = pd.DataFrame({'Level 2': level1+df.loc['Level 2'],
                    'Level 1': level1+0.999*n
                    }).T

sns.heatmap(tmp, annot=df, cmap=multi_cmap, vmin=0, vmax=n*n_levels,
            square=True, cbar_kws={'orientation': 'horizontal'})

Output:

Output with n = 10


Thank you! This does work, but I confess I am having trouble understanding how. Could you please explain what this color specification means?
 [(0.0, (0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765)),  (0.249, 'w'),  (0.25, (1.0, 0.4980392156862745, 0.054901960784313725)),  (0.499, 'w'),  (0.5, (0.17254901960784313, 0.6274509803921569, 0.17254901960784313)),  (0.749, 'w'),  (0.75, (0.8392156862745098, 0.15294117647058825, 0.1568627450980392)),  (1.0, 'w')]

It's [(breakpoint1, color1), (breakpoint2, color2), ...] where breakpoint is a number between 0 and 1 and the color a string ('w' = white) or a RGB tuple. Here the breakpoints for 4 levels are [0. , 0.249, 0.25, 0.499, 0.5, 0.749, 0.75, 1.], corresponding to the intervals 0->5, 5->10, 10->15, 15->20. Then the colors are interpolated between the breakpoints creating the gradient.

Ah I see. Thank you! And I suppose subtracting 0.001 reduces the shade every time slightly?

@KG no, it was to separate the end of a level with the start of the next one, but it's actually not needed, it would work without it (try to remove -0.001). The breakpoints are between 0 and 1, the colormap must start at 0 and end with 1, then the data is rescaled to 0->1 when plotted (which is why I'm passing vmin=0, vmax=n*n_levels).

@KG can you open a new question for that? This is probably more complex and would require extra details and demo

ok will do. But unfortunately this also doesn't work for two levels. For Level 2 I actually have 423 values. When I set n to 500, the heatmap is completely broken.

I have edited my question with a plot of what I see.

Difficult to comment without having the data, can you share it?

Actually nevermind. I figured out what I was doing wrong. Thank you very much for your help! I managed to do it for three levels too!
